# How to correctly encode ascii text with php?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, char

Alright - I use `file_get_contents()` to receive the content of a txt file. I checked with this line: `$encoding=mb_detect_encoding($texts, 'auto');` which encoding it is and the output was ascii.

Normally ascii is somehow utf-8 but instead of the long dash I get this funny symbols:

> â€“

With `$texts=iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $texts);` I was able to remove those symbols but I want to keep them.

I also tried to replace them with normal dashes:

```
$texts=str_replace('â€“', '-', $texts);
```

but that didn't work. Maybe there are other strange symbols - how could I encode them correctly or replace them with similiar symbols?

Answer (score 0):

This useful [forceutf8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) library that can handle and correct strings with mixed encoding:

> PHP Class Encoding featuring popular Encoding::toUTF8() function
>   --formerly known as forceUTF8()-- that fixes mixed encoded strings.

Comment: Thx! But following error occured: "Fatal error: Class 'Encoding' not found in ..." It's not a standard PHP function, right?

Comment: I downloaded Encoding.php from https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8 and used require_once() in my script to import it. Then following error occured: "Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script" - so I uncommented it (//namespace ForceUTF8;). Then I used the Encoding::toUTF8() function but nothing changed :(

Comment: I don't get it. I import Encoding.php and am not uncommenting the namespace line and get the error "Fatal error: Class 'Encoding' not found in ..." but the path is correct and the file is correct and my line of code in the main php is $text_content=file_get_contents(Encoding::toUTF8($text)); so normally it should work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer in this function from [this site](http://alanwhipple.com/2011/06/04/php-clean-encoding-issues-smart-curly-quotes-em-dashes/).

I tried so many different things but in the end this was the only thing that worked.

Comment: The function above from Alan Whipple is the following:

Answer (score 0):

The function, courtesy of Alan Whipple, that user2718671 references, in case the website is gone, is the following:

```
    function cleanEncoding( $text, $type='standard' ){
    // determine the encoding before we touch it
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1');
    // The characters to output
    if ( $type=='standard' ){
        $outp_chr = array('...',          "'",            "'",            '"',            '"',            'â¢',            '-',            '-'); // run of the mill standard characters
    } elseif ( $type=='reference' ) {
        $outp_chr = array('&#8230;',      '&#8216;',      '&#8217;',      '&#8220;',      '&#8221;',      '&#8226;',      '&#8211;',      '&#8212;'); // decimal numerical character references
    }
    // The characters to replace (purposely indented for comparison)
        $utf8_chr = array("\xe2\x80\xa6", "\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", '\xe2\x80\xa2', "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94"); // UTF-8 hex characters
        $winc_chr = array(chr(133),       chr(145),       chr(146),       chr(147),       chr(148),       chr(149),       chr(150),       chr(151)); // ASCII characters (found in Windows-1252)
    // First, replace UTF-8 characters.
    $text = str_replace( $utf8_chr, $outp_chr, $text);
    // Next, replace Windows-1252 characters.
    $text = str_replace( $winc_chr, $outp_chr, $text);
    // even if the string seems to be UTF-8, we can't trust it, so convert it to UTF-8 anyway
    $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $encoding);
    return $text;
    }
```